# Google Map not loading specifically in Android Lollipop and Marshmallow Google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to load google map with cluster, on android 5, 6 API level 21, 22 and 23 I'm having an issue that google map never loads. in other platforms its working fine, ie nougat, Oreo pie.

I've double checked google api console and changed api key aswell,no problems with runtime permissions infact i've also commented this line. 
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' and class path aswell.

other than this no logs are printed 
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 17194018

```
 override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
    googleMap = map

    try {
    //parsing dark map style to map view
        val success =
            map.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(context, R.raw.map_style_dark))
        if (!success) {
    //parsing failed
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.")
        }
    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
    //if style not found
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I was having same issue once I was working in an App. 
try to resume map in OnResume().

`override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        map.let{
            it.onResume()
        }
    }`
```

Comment: you saved my day. little silly mistake ruined my work. Thanks mate :)